# CSS/Jade/HTML: boxes won't inline properly

Tags: css, node.js, templates, pug, cascade

I have the following Jade template:

```
extends layout

block content
  h2 Characters and Portraits
  div(id="portraitsBox")
    - var portraits  = ["Clown-Fox", "Dragon-Bear", "Fish-Bear", "Deer-Wolf", "Salamander-Ant", "Side-Duck"];
    for filename in portraits
        - var url = "/images/portraits/" + filename.toLowerCase() + ".png"
        div(class="characterBox" id=filename)
          h3(class="characterName")= filename
          img(class="portrait" src= url)
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/characters.css')
```

Which pulls from the following CSS:

```
#portraitsBox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.characterBox {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 350px;
  display: inline;
}

.characterName {
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  font: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This works fine if I take out `display: inline`, but every time I try put it back in I get this garbage:

http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/characters

And the container `div` resizes itself to 169.9px wide!!?

What's going on here? I checked with Firebug and it doesn't look like any of the Bootstrap default stylings are over-riding my own CSS (they're called in the extended layout file) or anything like that, and there's nothing in the cascade that should be causing it, to my reckoning. When I look at the generated HTML all the elements are nested as expected, which was my next consideration so it doesn't seem to be anything silly I overlooked...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get this result: http://screencast.com/t/c06yM3cr

I am confused because you said that it works fine if you disable display inline, and when I tried that they were still displaying as block.

If your desired result is what I have in the sceenshot, all you have to do is set the wrapper #portraitsBox to display: flex.